# Shower valve causing hammering

Tags: shower, valve, water-hammer

I just had a plumber out to take a look at a pipe hammering issue I'm having.  He isolated the problem to the shower valve.  He turned off the water to the valve to demonstrate how the noise will stop when there is no water entering the value; he was right the noise stopped. He wants to replace the entire shower value.  Is there anything I could try before replacing the shower valve?

Comment: Is it an old valve???  Have you tried replacing just the cartridge?

Comment: I'll try that Jack, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned the plumber demonstrated that the noise would stop by turning off the water to the valve by using the shut offs next to it.  It turns out just turning off the shut offs slightly and not fully off would also cause the hammering to stop.  It's been a few days and and it hasn't returned.  Saved me a lot of money.

Answer (score 1):

"Water hammer" (the noise) is caused by suddenly stopping the flow of water in a pipe and creating a "shock wave" because water cannot compress and yet has kinetic energy when moving. The cure for water hammer is to have a valve that closes slowly so the kinetic energy dissipates slowly, or to trap air in the piping system so that the air can absorb the energy by compressing. That's why you will often see little "pipes to nowhere" inside of the walls.

[image]

There are also specific devices called "water hammer arresters" that are similar and have a little bladder or piston inside that serves the same function.

[image]

So the fact that it USED to work fine, points to something having changed. Fixing or replacing just the valve may NOT fix the problem. So for example if you have a piston type arrester on the hot side and the piston has failed, it no longer absorbs the shock wave. A good plumber would know this. So he may know this and by turning the water off to that valve, of course the problem goes away. He may be trying to up-sell you on replacing the entire shower valve because then he tears open the wall to replace it, he will also replace the arrester and this solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks JReaf.  I'm not sure if it has ever worked properly before. I moved in 6 months ago.  It looks like the bathroom was remodeled in the last 10 years ago.  I'll look to see if I can spot an arrester.

Comment: For what it's worth, the water hammer arrestors might not be adequate. Those 'pipes to nowhere' are much better solutions (when feasible) due to being far bigger. I replaced a basic washing machine with a high-efficiency LG one 6 or 7 years ago in a 1951 house and the LG one caused hammering even after installing water hammer arrestors on both lines into the washing machine. In this case it's most likely just that the pipes were too small/loose to silently handle the volume and pressure of water being pulled by the LG compared to the older, more basic washing machine.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue with a Danze shower valve. It would hammer loudly when turning it on and off. The problem is calcium/scale build-up in the valve. This can usually be resolved by replacing the cartridge, which is what I did. Depending on the make and age of the shower control the manufacturer may send you a new one free of charge as they did with mine which was about 5 years old. So I would suggest you call them first.
Another option is to remove the cartridge and soak it overnight in a decalcifying solution such as Lime Away or CLR. Although if you do this you will probably also have to replace any rubber washers or o-rings. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the tips HoneyDo.  I'll be sure to reach out to the manufacturer.  The hammering is caused when closing other facets around the house too; not just the shower. I'm not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, had/have this valve balance issue.  I identified the problem and have been attempting a more permanent solution for two years (I am not a slow learner, but I am curious).

I found/measured modestly unequal cold and hot water volumes entering the valve.  Hypothesis is the pipes are of unequal size somewhere in the supply or a copper pipe has narrowed (a victim of hard water?).  ADJUSTING the valve water stop temporarily addressed the knocking that was created when any water appliance in the house changed line pressure.  6 month fix.  REPLACING the water stops resulted in another 6 month fix.  The calcium deposits were obvious on the water stops (also good to know is Danze refers to the water stop as an adjustment valve as well a stop).  REPLACED the ceramic mixing cartridge and pressure balance cartridge.  This 2 year fix also resulted in seeing hard water calcium deposits on the cartridges, but no leaking and continued smooth adjustments between cold and hot supplies.  If you have followed my chronology, this process is at 4 years.  REPLACED all copper pipe in our home with PEX and bright in a new 1" service line from the meter (for more but related reason than the shower knock) with no impact on valve knock. WIPED the ceramic mixer and balancer valve components... Good for 6 months and calcium identified once again.

My RECOMMENDATION, though I have not found a perfect answer:

1. clean or replace all rubber parts and liberally grease with food grade silicone,
2. reduce water pressure (not volume) to 60#,
3. consider a water conditioner that addresses the sediment or deposit issues that may exist in your water service (assuming you are on utility supplied water, they should be pleased that you are asking them for there filed government testing results for chemical and mineral content).  I am contemplating water softening which removes calcium and some other minerals count in our sources for local water).
4. If you can identify pressure/volume difference between hot and cold water, you may be successful in, again, adjusting a water stop at the valve.  The water heater itself may be affecting the overly temperamental Danze valve.